# Negative Angles

Tags: geometry, angle

A lot of times text books refer to the measure of angles with a little arrow (see picture below).

[image]

But to go clockwise they represent it as below.
[image]

The thing is and maybe this is just me, but I think of this as a vector where it goes around the other way (so it would be just like the angle in the first picture).

> $\textbf{Question:}$ Is there such a thing as angles represented in this way where they are assumed to act like vectors in space in this way? I just want more insight as to how to denote these angles correctly. For instance, could I denote an angle like below to denote a clockwise direction instead of the second picture?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" For instance, could I denote an angle like below to denote a clockwise direction instead of the second picture?", yes, you can, providing you show the angle of orientation. Such angles are called oriented angles.

Comment: So in the context of oriented angles, would the second picture be just like the first? Just in context of the pictures (ignore the wording).

Comment: "just like the first". Depends what you mean. All of the pictures are oriented angles. The last picture has a different reference of angle than the two first ones. So it's "the same" in a way. Not sure what you mean by "the same"?

Comment: Good point. I mean in the context of oriented angles, I think of the second picture (ignoring the words) to go around counterclockwise. Is that the case here?

Comment: Huh, yes. It is. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, $0^{\circ}$ is usually taken to point east and counterclockwise angles are usually taken to be positive (possibly because the mapping $x \mapsto \exp(2\pi ix)$ from the real line to the complex plane  maps $0$ to $1$ and wraps the real line around the unit circle counterclockwise). In navigation, $0^{\circ}$ points north and clockwise angles (bearings) are taken to be positive (for reasons I am too uncertain to guess at).